# faster way for "for loop" in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I want to fill the unit circle with dots. But the code I have written is very slow. Is there an alternative that Matlab can run faster?

```
y = linspace(-1, 1, 200);
x = linspace(-1, 1, 200);
for i = 1: length(x)
    for j = 1: length(y)
        if (x(i)^2 + y(j)^2 < 1)
            plot(x(i),y(j),'.');               
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than looping through every permutation of `x` and `y`, you can use `meshgrid` to create two matrices (`xx` and `yy`) where each corresponding value in the two is a unique combination of `x` and `y` values. You can then use these matrices to evaluate your conditional (`xx.^2 + yy.^2 < 1`) at once. This will result in a logical array the size of `xx` that we can use to plot just the points that were inside of the unit circle.

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x, y);
inside = xx.^2 + yy.^2 < 1;

% Now plot just these points
plot(xx(inside), yy(inside), '.');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It's really helpful